# Import Channel Entries into New Channel?

Tags: datagrab, export, solspace-importer

We are in the process of architecting an upgrade for a site, and in the process are considering consolidating multiple channels into a single channel. (in the process utilizing new templates designed around the single channel)  BUT, we have a significant amount of entries in the original channels.

Assuming we set the new channel's fields to the correct configuration, can we use one of the import tools to migrate entries from one channel to another instead of manually needing to recreate entries?  Or would we need to export first then reimport?

Any suggestions or guidance to ensure minimal repetition of work would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IF the channels share the same custom field group you should be able to use a bit of SQL to check for a specific channel_id and convert it to the channel_id you are keeping.

If the channels do not share the same custom field groups you will need to export the data. This can be as simple as creating a template and setting it to XML, or using one of the export add-ons to export the relevant data. From there you would have to use Datagrab or Solspace importer to import the data back into EE.

Answer (score 0):

If it where me I would use this addon to export your data from the old channel into a csv.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export

Then use this addon to import that csv into the new channel.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab